# Is there a known issue using Delphi XE2 ADO components with the SQLOLEDB.1 provider?

Tags: delphi, ado, delphi-xe2

I am trying to troubleshoot an issue with a new release of my application. The symptom is that the application gets an access violation exception in SQLOLEDB.dll when trying to update a row in a SQL table using TADOQuery.ExecSQL.

I have not been able to reproduce the problem in my development environment, nor has my organization's QA team. Our users have been hitting it pretty hard though.

Two big changes between this problem release and its predecessor are that 1) we moved from Delphi 2006 to DXE2 and 2) we switched from XPSP3 to Win7SP1 as a build environment. The users are still on XPSP3, in a pretty tightly controlled change management regime.

Editing to add: madExcept bug report

```
date/time         : 2012-06-27, 08:24:18, 775ms
computer name     : 
user name         : 
registered owner  : 
operating system  : Windows XP Service Pack 3 build 2600
system language   : English
system up time    : 48 minutes 7 seconds
program up time   : 7 minutes 48 seconds
processors        : 2x Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E8400 @ 3.00GHz
physical memory   : 854/2030 MB (free/total)
free disk space   : (C:) 47.30 GB
display mode      : 1024x768, 32 bit
process id        : $3d4
allocated memory  : 14.44 MB
command line      : 
executable        : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe
exec. date/time   : 2012-06-15 11:39
version           : 3.5.0.24
compiled with     : Delphi XE2
madExcept version : 3.0n
contact name      : 
contact email     : 
callstack crc     : $4dd03195, $4d9f14cf, $4d9f14cf
exception number  : 1
exception class   : EAccessViolation
exception message : Access violation at address 4DD03195 in module 'sqloledb.dll'. Read of address 03217000.

main thread ($938):
4dd03195 +000 sqloledb.dll
007e71d9 +091 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe Data.Win.ADODB              TADOCommand.Execute
007f08a5 +03d xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe Data.Win.ADODB              TADOQuery.ExecSQL
00825f6a +5fa xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe uauthorization    1528  +74 TAuthorization.SynchAuthToSQL
00822fd7 +d43 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe uauthorization    1228 +148 TAuthorization.Save
00b656a2 +15a xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe form              1489  +33 TfrmMain.CreateOrEditAuthorization
00b6600f +02b xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe form              1641   +2 TfrmMain.actEditAuthorizationExecute
0048834f +00f xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe System.Classes              TBasicAction.Execute
004f4441 +031 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe Vcl.ActnList                TContainedAction.Execute
004f522c +050 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe Vcl.ActnList                TCustomAction.Execute
00488213 +013 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe System.Classes              TBasicActionLink.Execute
00508a00 +058 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe Vcl.Controls                TControl.Click
006dbd31 +051 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe AdvGlowButton     3040   +9 TAdvCustomGlowButton.Click
00508ec1 +065 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe Vcl.Controls                TControl.WMLButtonUp
006dca97 +397 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe AdvGlowButton     3508 +126 TAdvCustomGlowButton.WMLButtonUp
005084bc +2d4 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe Vcl.Controls                TControl.WndProc
0050ce07 +5b3 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe Vcl.Controls                TWinControl.WndProc
0050c45c +02c xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe Vcl.Controls                TWinControl.MainWndProc
00489044 +014 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe System.Classes              StdWndProc
7e418a0b +00a USER32.dll                                        DispatchMessageW
005eb023 +0f3 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe Vcl.Forms                   TApplication.ProcessMessage
005eb066 +00a xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe Vcl.Forms                   TApplication.HandleMessage
005eb399 +0c9 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe Vcl.Forms                   TApplication.Run
00b84f68 +0ac xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx   64   +8 initialization

thread $1054:
7c90daa8 +0a ntdll.dll                       NtReplyWaitReceivePortEx
004bc199 +0d xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe madExcept CallThreadProcSafe
004bc203 +37 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe madExcept ThreadExceptFrame
>> created by main thread ($938) at:
77e7d10d +00 RPCRT4.dll

thread $1028:
7c90df48 +00a ntdll.dll                       NtWaitForMultipleObjects004bc199 +00d xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe madExcept CallThreadProcSafe
004bc203 +037 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe madExcept ThreadExceptFrame
>> created by main thread ($938) at:
5b891d46 +1f1 NETAPI32.dll                    Netbios

thread $1058:
7c90df58 +0a ntdll.dll                       NtWaitForSingleObject
7c8025d5 +85 kernel32.dll                    WaitForSingleObjectEx
7c80253d +0d kernel32.dll                    WaitForSingleObject
004bc199 +0d xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe madExcept CallThreadProcSafe
004bc203 +37 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe madExcept ThreadExceptFrame
>> created by main thread ($938) at:
76663fb6 +00 comsvcs.dll

thread $1384:
7c90daa8 +0a ntdll.dll                       NtReplyWaitReceivePortEx
004bc199 +0d xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe madExcept CallThreadProcSafe
004bc203 +37 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe madExcept ThreadExceptFrame
>> created by thread $1054 at:
77e7d10d +00 RPCRT4.dll

modules:
00400000 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe 3.5.0.24         \\xxxxxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxx\xxxx
02bd0000 msadcer.dll           2.81.1132.0      C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\msadc
02ee0000 SQLOLEDB.RLL          2000.85.1132.0   C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\Ole DB
03340000 xpsp2res.dll          5.1.2600.5512    C:\WINDOWS\system32
10000000 sxwmon32.dll          4.4.1401.0       C:\WINDOWS\system32
4dd00000 sqloledb.dll          2000.85.1132.0   C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\Ole DB
4de10000 msado15.dll           2.81.3012.0      C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\ado
4ec50000 gdiplus.dll           5.2.6002.22791   C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.GdiPlus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.0.6002.22791_x-ww_c8dff154
5ad70000 uxtheme.dll           6.0.2900.5512    C:\WINDOWS\system32
5b860000 NETAPI32.dll          5.1.2600.5694    C:\WINDOWS\system32
5edd0000 olepro32.dll          5.1.2600.5512    C:\WINDOWS\system32
605d0000 mslbui.dll            5.1.2600.5512    C:\WINDOWS\system32
60e30000 MSDATL3.dll           2.81.1132.0      C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\Ole DB
61880000 oleacc.dll            7.0.2600.6153    C:\WINDOWS\system32
662b0000 hnetcfg.dll           5.1.2600.5512    C:\WINDOWS\system32
68000000 rsaenh.dll            5.1.2600.5507    C:\WINDOWS\system32
68100000 dssenh.dll            5.1.2600.5507    C:\WINDOWS\system32
6d4f0000 DBNETLIB.DLL          2000.85.1132.0   C:\WINDOWS\system32
71a50000 mswsock.dll           5.1.2600.5625    C:\WINDOWS\System32
71a90000 wshtcpip.dll          5.1.2600.5512    C:\WINDOWS\System32
71aa0000 WS2HELP.dll           5.1.2600.5512    C:\WINDOWS\system32
71ab0000 WS2_32.dll            5.1.2600.5512    C:\WINDOWS\system32
71ad0000 wsock32.dll           5.1.2600.5512    C:\WINDOWS\system32
71f80000 security.dll          5.1.2600.5512    C:\WINDOWS\system32
73000000 winspool.drv          5.1.2600.5512    C:\WINDOWS\system32
73160000 oledb32.dll           2.81.1132.0      C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\Ole DB
73bc0000 dciman32.dll          5.1.2600.5512    C:\WINDOWS\system32
74060000 msadce.dll            2.81.3002.0      C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\msadc
74720000 MSCTF.dll             5.1.2600.5512    C:\WINDOWS\system32
74e30000 RICHED20.DLL          5.30.23.1230     C:\WINDOWS\system32
750b0000 RESUTILS.DLL          5.1.2600.5512    C:\WINDOWS\system32
750f0000 MTXCLU.DLL            2001.12.4414.706 C:\WINDOWS\system32
75130000 colbact.DLL           2001.12.4414.700 C:\WINDOWS\system32
75350000 OLEDB32R.DLL          2.81.1132.0      C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\Ole DB
755c0000 msctfime.ime          5.1.2600.5512    C:\WINDOWS\system32
76360000 WINSTA.dll            5.1.2600.5512    C:\WINDOWS\system32
76380000 msimg32.dll           5.1.2600.5512    C:\WINDOWS\system32
76390000 IMM32.DLL             5.1.2600.5512    C:\WINDOWS\system32
763b0000 comdlg32.dll          6.0.2900.5512    C:\WINDOWS\system32
765b0000 MSDART.DLL            2.81.1132.0      C:\WINDOWS\system32
76620000 comsvcs.dll           2001.12.4414.702 C:\WINDOWS\system32
76790000 cryptdll.dll          5.1.2600.5512    C:\WINDOWS\system32
767a0000 ntdsapi.dll           5.1.2600.5512    C:\WINDOWS\system32
767f0000 schannel.dll          5.1.2600.6175    C:\WINDOWS\system32
769c0000 USERENV.dll           5.1.2600.5512    C:\WINDOWS\system32
76b40000 winmm.dll             5.1.2600.6160    C:\WINDOWS\system32
76d10000 CLUSAPI.DLL           5.1.2600.5512    C:\WINDOWS\system32
76d60000 iphlpapi.dll          5.1.2600.5512    C:\WINDOWS\system32
76f20000 DNSAPI.dll            5.1.2600.6089    C:\WINDOWS\system32
76f50000 wtsapi32.dll          5.1.2600.5512    C:\WINDOWS\system32
76f60000 WLDAP32.dll           5.1.2600.5512    C:\WINDOWS\system32
76fb0000 winrnr.dll            5.1.2600.5512    C:\WINDOWS\System32
76fc0000 rasadhlp.dll          5.1.2600.5512    C:\WINDOWS\system32
76fd0000 CLBCATQ.DLL           2001.12.4414.700 C:\WINDOWS\system32
77050000 COMRes.dll            2001.12.4414.700 C:\WINDOWS\system32
77120000 oleaut32.dll          5.1.2600.6058    C:\WINDOWS\system32
773d0000 comctl32.dll          6.0.2900.6028    C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.2600.6028_x-ww_61e65202
774e0000 ole32.dll             5.1.2600.6168    C:\WINDOWS\system32
77a80000 crypt32.dll           5.131.2600.6149  C:\WINDOWS\system32
77b20000 MSASN1.dll            5.1.2600.5875    C:\WINDOWS\system32
77c00000 version.dll           5.1.2600.5512    C:\WINDOWS\system32
77c10000 msvcrt.dll            7.0.2600.5512    C:\WINDOWS\system32
77c70000 msv1_0.dll            5.1.2600.5876    C:\WINDOWS\system32
77dd0000 ADVAPI32.dll          5.1.2600.5755    C:\WINDOWS\system32
77e70000 RPCRT4.dll            5.1.2600.6022    C:\WINDOWS\system32
77f10000 GDI32.dll             5.1.2600.5698    C:\WINDOWS\system32
77f60000 SHLWAPI.dll           6.0.2900.5912    C:\WINDOWS\system32
77fe0000 Secur32.dll           5.1.2600.5834    C:\WINDOWS\system32
7c800000 kernel32.dll          5.1.2600.5781    C:\WINDOWS\system32
7c900000 ntdll.dll             5.1.2600.6055    C:\WINDOWS\system32
7c9c0000 shell32.dll           6.0.2900.6072    C:\WINDOWS\system32
7e410000 USER32.dll            5.1.2600.5512    C:\WINDOWS\system32

processes:
0000 Idle                  0   0
0004 System                0   0
07dc smss.exe              0   0
0284 csrss.exe             0   0
0320 winlogon.exe          0   0
0368 services.exe          0   0
0374 lsass.exe             0   0
0440 ati2evxx.exe          0   0
0450 svchost.exe           0   0
04ac svchost.exe           0   0
0550 svchost.exe           0   0
05ac svchost.exe           0   0
064c svchost.exe           0   0
0674 DVService.exe         0   0
06d8 spoolsv.exe           0   0
0758 ac.sharedstore.exe    0   0
0770 scardsvr.exe          0   0
0118 BESClient.exe         0   0
023c BESClientHelper.exe   0   0
02d8 FireSvc.exe           0   0
02ec PMService.exe         0   0
0310 HIPSvc.exe            0   0
03b4 EngineServer.exe      0   0
04c0 FrameworkService.exe  0   0
05c0 VsTskMgr.exe          0   0
0614 mdm.exe               0   0
06b0 mfevtps.exe           0   0
07ac NwmSvc.exe            0   0
00f8 scomc.exe             0   0
01b0 Svchost32.exe         0   0
0224 naPrdMgr.exe          0   0
0288 uphclean.exe          0   0
0294 VergenceLocator.exe   0   0
0538 WakeUpAgt.exe         0   0
0814 Mcshield.exe          0   0
095c CcmExec.exe           0   0
097c mfeann.exe            0   0
0984 alg.exe               0   0
0be0 wmiprvse.exe          0   0
0db0 wmiprvse.exe          0   0
0c04 acevents.exe          0   0
0de0 ati2evxx.exe          0   0
05fc Explorer.EXE          342 235 normal C:\WINDOWS
0908 NWMCLI.EXE            14  6   normal C:\Program Files\1E\Agent\NightWatchman
0f40 RTNotify.exe          65  35  normal C:\Program Files\Lumension\Endpoint Security\Client
00dc MOM.exe               11  15  normal C:\Program Files\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static
0ce4 BGinfo.exe            54  47  normal C:\WINDOWS\system32
021c smax4pnp.exe          19  7   normal C:\Program Files\Analog Devices\Core
0c34 Clagent.exe           47  23  normal C:\Program Files\Vista\Broker
0f38 UdaterUI.exe          52  41  normal C:\Program Files\McAfee\Common Framework
0c10 GrooveMonitor.exe     11  4   normal C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12
0e74 McTray.exe            123 113 normal C:\Program Files\McAfee\Common Framework
0d8c FireTray.exe          37  17  normal C:\Program Files\McAfee\Host Intrusion Prevention
0b70 acevents.exe          11  9   normal C:\Program Files\ActivIdentity\ActivClient
0378 accrdsub.exe          50  22  normal C:\Program Files\ActivIdentity\ActivClient
057c DVTrayApp.exe         22  14  normal C:\Program Files\Tumbleweed\Desktop Validator
0a74 ctfmon.exe            103 49  normal C:\WINDOWS\system32
0fc0 acsagent.exe          23  19  normal C:\Program Files\ActivIdentity\ActivClient
0580 BESClientUI.exe       121 91  normal C:\Program Files\BigFix Enterprise\BES Client
0f54 OUTLOOK.EXE           463 267 normal C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12
0474 ccc.exe               44  51  normal C:\Program Files\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static
147c xxxxxxxxx.EXE         246 331 normal \\xxxxxxxxxx\xxxx\xxxx
1580 C2W_CM.exe            8   5   normal C:\Program Files\Sentillion\DesktopComponents\COMAdapters
0a0c r2win.exe             214 117 normal C:\Program Files\Attachmate\Reflection
14fc WINWORD.EXE           268 105 normal C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12
03d4 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe 216 151 normal \\xxxxxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxx\xxxx

hardware:
+ Computer
  - ACPI Multiprocessor PC
+ Disk drives
  - SAMSUNG HD083GJ
+ Display adapters
  - ATI Radeon HD 3450 - Dell Optiplex (driver 8.513.1.0)
  - ConfigMgr Remote Control Driver
+ DVD/CD-ROM drives
  - HL-DT-ST DVD+-RW GT10N
+ Human Interface Devices
  - USB Human Interface Device
  - USB Human Interface Device
+ IDE ATA/ATAPI controllers
  - Intel(R) ICH10 Family 2 port Serial ATA Storage Controller 2 - 3A06 (driver 9.0.0.1005)
  - Intel(R) ICH10 Family 4 port Serial ATA Storage Controller 1 - 3A00 (driver 9.0.0.1005)
  - Primary IDE Channel
  - Primary IDE Channel
  - Secondary IDE Channel
  - Secondary IDE Channel
  - Standard Dual Channel PCI IDE Controller
+ Keyboards
  - HID Keyboard Device
+ Mice and other pointing devices
  - HID-compliant mouse
+ Monitors
  - Plug and Play Monitor
  - Plug and Play Monitor
+ Network adapters
  - Intel(R) 82567LM-3 Gigabit Network Connection (driver 10.3.39.0)
+ Ports (COM & LPT)
  - Communications Port (COM1)
  - ECP Printer Port (LPT1)
  - Intel(R) Remote PC Assist Technology - SOL (COM4) (driver 5.5.0.1057)
+ Processors
  - Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E8400  @ 3.00GHz
  - Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E8400  @ 3.00GHz
+ Smart card readers
  - Smart Card Reader Keyboard (driver 1.0.0.2)
+ Sound, video and game controllers
  - Audio Codecs
  - Legacy Audio Drivers
  - Legacy Video Capture Devices
  - Media Control Devices
  - SoundMAX Integrated Digital High Definition Audio (driver 5.10.1.5851)
  - Video Codecs
+ System devices
  - ACPI Fixed Feature Button
  - ACPI Power Button
  - Direct memory access controller
  - High precision event timer
  - Intel(R) 4 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port - 2E11 (driver 9.0.0.1009)
  - Intel(R) 4 Series Chipset Processor to I/O Controller - 2E10 (driver 9.0.0.1009)
  - Intel(R) 82801 PCI Bridge - 244E (driver 7.0.0.1011)
  - Intel(R) ICH10 Family PCI Express Root Port 1 - 3A70 (driver 9.0.0.1009)
  - Intel(R) ICH10 Family PCI Express Root Port 2 - 3A72 (driver 9.0.0.1009)
  - Intel(R) ICH10 Family SMBus Controller - 3A60 (driver 9.0.0.1005)
  - Intel(R) ICH10D LPC Interface Controller - 3A1A (driver 9.0.0.1009)
  - Intel(R) Management Engine Interface
  - ISAPNP Read Data Port
  - Logical Disk Manager
  - Microcode Update Device
  - Microsoft ACPI-Compliant System
  - Microsoft System Management BIOS Driver
  - Microsoft UAA Bus Driver for High Definition Audio
  - Microsoft Windows Management Interface for ACPI
  - Numeric data processor
  - OpenManage Client Instrumentation device driver (driver 7.6.0.732)
  - PCI bus
  - Plug and Play Software Device Enumerator
  - Printer Port Logical Interface
  - Programmable interrupt controller
  - System board
  - System CMOS/real time clock
  - System speaker
  - System timer
  - Terminal Server Device Redirector
  - Terminal Server Keyboard Driver
  - Terminal Server Mouse Driver
  - Volume Manager
+ Universal Serial Bus controllers
  - Intel(R) ICH10 Family USB Enhanced Host Controller - 3A6A (driver 9.0.0.1005)
  - Intel(R) ICH10 Family USB Enhanced Host Controller - 3A6C (driver 9.0.0.1005)
  - Intel(R) ICH10 Family USB Universal Host Controller - 3A64 (driver 9.0.0.1005)
  - Intel(R) ICH10 Family USB Universal Host Controller - 3A65 (driver 9.0.0.1005)
  - Intel(R) ICH10 Family USB Universal Host Controller - 3A66 (driver 9.0.0.1005)
  - Intel(R) ICH10 Family USB Universal Host Controller - 3A67 (driver 9.0.0.1005)
  - Intel(R) ICH10 Family USB Universal Host Controller - 3A68 (driver 9.0.0.1005)
  - Intel(R) ICH10 Family USB Universal Host Controller - 3A69 (driver 9.0.0.1005)
  - USB Composite Device
  - USB Root Hub
  - USB Root Hub
  - USB Root Hub
  - USB Root Hub
  - USB Root Hub
  - USB Root Hub
  - USB Root Hub
  - USB Root Hub

cpu registers:
eax = 00000ff8
ebx = 03206e38
ecx = 0000007d
edx = 00000ff8
esi = 03216ffd
edi = 03209244
eip = 4dd03195
esp = 0012e520
ebp = 0012e650

stack dump:
0012e520  20 94 0c 03 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 02 02 02 02  ................
0012e530  20 94 0c 03 02 02 02 02 - 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 4f  ...............O
0012e540  4c 45 44 42 53 53 44 65 - f1 71 21 03 64 34 00 00  LEDBSSDe.q!.d4..
0012e550  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
0012e560  33 64 34 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 0b 6c 00 00  3d4..........l..
0012e570  90 ed 12 00 38 00 00 00 - 78 3b 20 03 18 d6 20 03  ....8...x;......
0012e580  9b 4c d4 4d 78 3b 20 03 - ff 03 00 00 1f 5f fe 77  .L.Mx;......._.w
0012e590  d8 e5 12 00 37 5f fe 77 - 00 00 00 00 02 02 02 02  ....7_.w........
0012e5a0  02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 - 02 02 02 00 c0 e5 12 00  ................
0012e5b0  d5 48 12 77 06 c4 13 77 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  .H.w...w........
0012e5c0  0a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ec f0 12 00 e8 e8 12 00  ................
0012e5d0  c0 33 0e 03 09 04 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 2c e6 12 00  .3..........,...
0012e5e0  e5 c0 13 77 09 04 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 06 00 00 00  ...w............
0012e5f0  ec f0 12 00 e8 e8 12 00 - 01 00 00 00 ff 1f 00 00  ................
0012e600  00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
0012e610  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
0012e620  00 00 00 00 75 e6 12 00 - 00 00 00 00 84 e6 12 01  ....u...........
0012e630  84 e6 12 00 ad 02 15 77 - 5c e6 12 00 74 e6 12 00  .......w\...t...
0012e640  00 00 08 00 4c e6 12 00 - 02 02 02 02 0b 6c 00 00  ....L........l..
0012e650  78 e6 12 00 89 75 d2 4d - 20 94 0c 03 e0 c8 20 03  x....u.M........

disassembling:
[...]
00825f59        mov     eax, [eax]
00825f5b        call    -$34dc4 ($7f119c)      ; dssLog.TLogFile.Add00825f60 1528   mov     eax, [$b94e44]
00825f65        mov     eax, [eax]
00825f67        mov     eax, [eax+$64]
00825f6a      > call    -$35707 ($7f0868)      ; Data.Win.ADODB.TADOQuery.ExecSQL
00825f6f 1529   mov     eax, [$b944bc]
00825f74        mov     eax, [eax]
00825f76        mov     edx, $8269a8
00825f7b        call    -$34de4 ($7f119c)      ; dssLog.TLogFile.Add00825f80 1531   mov     eax, [$b94e44]
[...]

error details:
```

Editing to add: procedure where crash happens (sorry, it's been the victim of some vcs merges that didn't preserve indentation). The offending line is the `dmSQL.adoGenericQuery.ExecSQL;` just before the end:

```
procedure TAuthorization.SynchAuthToSQL(sStationIFN:string='';bForceUpdate:boolean=false);
const
  CountQuery = 'select count(*) from DSS_Authorizations'+
    ' where AuthIEN = :authIEN '+
    ' and authstationifn = :stationIFN' +
    ' and patientien = :patientIEN ';
var
    sStart,sEnd:string;
    sDxStripped: string;
  i: integer;
begin
    log.add('Synch Auth to SQL: '+FAuthIEN);
    if FAuthIEN = '' then
        exit;
    if sStationIFN = '' then
    sStationIFN := dmBroker.CurrentVistaStation.StationNumber;
    sStart := FormatDateTime('mm/dd/yyyy',FMDateTimeToTDateTime(FAuthFromDateVista));
    sEnd := FormatDateTime('mm/dd/yyyy',FMDateTimeToTDateTime(FAuthToDateVista));

    log.add('Begin auth count');
    //First the main authorizations part
  dmSQL.adoGenericQuery.SQL.Text := CountQuery;
  with dmSQL.adoGenericQuery.Parameters do
  begin
    FindParam('authIEN').Value := FAuthIEN;
    FindParam('stationIFN').Value := sStationIFN;
    FindParam('patientIEN').Value := FPatient.InternalValue;
  end;
    dmSQL.adoGenericQuery.Open;
    if dmSQL.adoGenericQuery.Fields[0].Value = 0 then
    begin
    InsertAuthToSQL;
    end
    else if bForceUpdate then
    begin
        //Update-deliberately does not update the ImportedFromVista and DateCreated fields
    dmSQL.adoGenericQuery.SQL.Text :=
      'update DSS_Authorizations set' +
      ' DateStart = :DateStart' +
      ',DateEnd = :DateEnd' +
      ',VendorIEN = :VendorIEN' +
      ',FacilityIEN = :FacilityIEN' +
      ',DXCode1= :DXCode1' +
      ',DXCode2 = :DXCode2' +
      ',DXCode3 = :DXCode3' +
      ',TreatmentTypeIEN = :TreatmentTypeIEN' +
      ',TypeofCareIEN = :TypeofCareIEN' +
      ',PatientTypeIEN = :PatientTypeIEN' +
      ',PurposeOfVisitIEN = :PurposeOfVisitIEN' +
      ',Remarks = :Remarks' +
      ',ClerkIEN = :ClerkIEN' +
      ',CostRecovery = :CostRecovery' +
      ',AccidentRelated = :AccidentRelated' +
      ',LastEditedBy = :LastEditedBy' +
      ',LastEditedDT = :LastEditedDT' +
      ',ContractID = :ContractID' +
      ' where AuthIEN =:AuthIEN and ' +
      ' AuthStationIFN = :AuthStationIFN and' +
      ' PatientIEN = :PatientIEN';
    with dmSQL.adoGenericQuery.Parameters do
    begin
      FindParam('DateStart').Value := sStart;
      FindParam('DateEnd').Value := sEnd;
      FindParam('VendorIEN').Value := FVendor.InternalValue;
      FindParam('FacilityIEN').Value := FLocation.IEN;
      FindParam('DXCode1').Value := FDXLine1;
      FindParam('DXCode2').Value := FDXLine2;
      FindParam('DXCode3').Value := FDXLine3;
      FindParam('TreatmentTypeIEN').Value := FTreatmentType.InternalValue;
      FindParam('TypeofCareIEN').Value := FTypeOfCare.InternalValue;
      FindParam('PatientTypeIEN').Value := FPatientType.InternalValue;
      FindParam('PurposeOfVisitIEN').Value := FPurpose.IEN;
      FindParam('Remarks').Value := FRemarks;
      FindParam('ClerkIEN').Value := FClerk.InternalValue;
      FindParam('CostRecovery').Value := BoolToOneZeroString(FCostRecovery);
      FindParam('AccidentRelated').Value := BoolToOneZeroString(FAccidentRelated);
      FindParam('LastEditedBy').Value := dmBroker.dssBroker.UserDuz + ';' + dmBroker.dssBroker.UserName;
      FindParam('LastEditedDT').Value := Now;
      FindParam('ContractID').Value := FContract.ExternalValue;
      FindParam('AuthIEN').Value := FAuthIEN;
      FindParam('AuthStationIFN').Value := sStationIFN;
      FindParam('PatientIEN').Value := FPatient.InternalValue;
    end;
    log.add('Begin update of existing auth: '+ dmSQL.adoGenericQuery.SQL.Text);
    dmSQL.adoGenericQuery.ExecSQL;
        log.add('Update done');
    end;
    dmSQL.adoGenericQuery.close;
    log.add('Auth synch done');
end;
```

Comment: One thing I would try is to use a tool like madExcept/eurekaLog/... to get a more detailed error log of what is happening. Also, against what DBMS is the update executed? Any change there? What is the specific error message you are getting now?

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, we've been using ADO/SQLOLEDB.1 extremely commonly, on Delphi 7, 2010, and XE2, and never had problems like this. Probably 80% of our customers are still on XP.

Comment: Agree with @Lieven. You need to capture the call stack on the end user's system so you can find out where's its blowing up.. Unfortunately Delphi's exception hierarchy doesn't provided this by default. It only provides hooks. 3rd party loggers like MadExcept and EurekaLog use these hooks to get the full stack.

Comment: Lieven, we are usin madExcept: it's how I know where the error is ocurring. The database is SQL Server 2K5. The madExcept exception message is "exception message : Access violation at address 4DD03195 in module 'sqloledb.dll'. Read of address xxxxxxxx." That is, the 'at address' part (instruction pointer, I assume) is always the same, but the address being read varies.

Comment: @wades - Not my cup of tea but I would suggest you to post any relevant information regarding this error. The entire madExcept log would be a good start. It includes the used version of sqloledb for starters and a complete stack trace leading up to the error.

Comment: @wades - Something you might look into is the default string type being unicode in DelphiXE. Do you resolved all hints and/or warnings when converting to DelphiXE? How did you resolve them?

Comment: @wades - If you apply the update that's written to the log in ssms, does that work? I notice the client uses sqloledb version 2000.85.1132.0. Can you replace it with a more recent version and verify if the error persists?

Comment: @wade - On a side note and I doubt it matters but the code you've shown doesn't match up with the madExcept log.

Comment: Try turning on FastMM full-debug mode.  Might find your "free and then use free'd object" crash for you.

Comment: You realize that you open dmSQL.adoGenericQuery just after the with block but do not close it before you hit the ExecSQL in the lower if block. Of course this assumes that you have bForceUpdate set to true.

Comment: @Lieven, "If you apply the update that's written to the log in ssms" I don't understand this. Yes the client is using an oldish version of SQLOLEDB, but it's current for XPSP3, I think. I am actually hoping that this turns out to be the answer, but need to make that case to convince their change control board.

Comment: @Warren P, nice try but I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: @Jeremy, the assignment of a new value to TADOQuery.SQL causes an implicit close. Yes, bForceUpdate is true when this happens.

Comment: I understand that implicitly it should close but in the past when playing with ADO implicit does not always mean it will.

Comment: @wades - This line `log.add('Begin update of existing auth: '+ dmSQL.adoGenericQuery.SQL.Text);` writes the SQL statement to a log file. Can you copy/paste and execute this statement in SSMS? *(surround it with a begin tran ... rollback tran)*

Comment: @Lieven, the SQL update does execute correctly in SQL Server Mgmt. Studio (that's what you mean by SSMS, right?)

Comment: @wades - Yes it is. I still *suspect* the change to be unicode related. Do your users get the AV with every update or just with specific ones? When you look at the update statement, are there any special characters in it? Can you try performing the update through msAccess using that provider? Note that all this is just to drill down to the problem *(wich I suspect to be the dll not being able to handle unicode correctly)*

Comment: @Lieven, the error is highly intermittent. This application has pretty extensive logging, and we have a case where the error occurred after a single exercise of the simplest use case: the total uptime from startup to crash was a little over a minute, and all of the data coming in was captured. I got on a livemeeting with the user and got him to reconstruct what he'd been doing, with the same records, and the error didn't occur. The captured data didn't contain anything that wasn't a printable ASCII glyph, space, or cr/lf sequence.

Comment: @wades - As a last resort, you can run `procdump` to attach to your executable and write a dump file when an unhandled exception occurs *(much like madExcept but with way more information)*. You can analyze the dumpfile offline afterwards with `Windbg` *(or ask assistance online)*. The chances of this pointing to the dll as culprit seem very likely so while this might lead you to the root cause of the AV, it will not solve your problem.

Comment: @Lieven, I have some experience with `windbg` and crash analysis, but assumed it would be close to useless with Delphi programs. Getting the users to use procdump might be as hard a getting them to speculatively change MDAC components as well.

Comment: @wades - If you can't bother your users with this, your only option would be to set up a test environment, equivallent to what your users have and do your debugging there.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is a specific memory corruption bug in your app. It could in fact be caused by something in XE2 VCL or RTL, but is more likely something broken in your code, such as a bad port from Ansi to Unicode.

You state that the move was from Delphi 2006 (String=AnsiString) to XE2 (String=UnicodeString).  Any of the following in your code:

- Any untyped var parameters?
- Any place where you assume Sizeof(Char)=Sizeof(Byte)?
- Any place where you cast to or from PChar when you should have cast to/from PAnsiChar, because PChar is a pointer to UnicodeChar in XE2 but PChar in 2006 is a pointer to AnsiChar.

Comment: We never did resolve why this was happening, but eventually it stopped as mysteriously as it started, possibly due to the users eventually updating to Windows 7.